# Why using toArray filter with ng-repeat and an object of strings causes an infinite digest loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I would like to use the **orderBy** filter with the ng-repeat directive while iterating over an objects properties.
As the orderBy filter only works with Array, the [Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties) suggests to use the **toArray** filter.

The toArray filter works like a charm with object-properties like:

```
var obj = {
  a: { name: 'A' },
  b: { name: 'B' },
  c: { name: 'C' }
};
```

But it causes an **infinite digest loop** when used with non-object properties:

```
var obj = {
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C'
};
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1A6cwp) illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that anyway, filters are generally bad idea when transforming data, cos it will get recalculated every time digest cycle makes a loop.  Your plunker does not work, so it is hard to say why, but looking at code I would say that it does make completly new array with each digest loop, and in case of objects it adds $key property, which helps stoping digest cycle. It cannot add such property to strings. But I'm not really sure about that.

Edit:
when you add console.log to toArray:

```
return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        var value = obj[key];

        console.log(key, value);

        return angular.isObject(value) ?
          Object.defineProperty(value, '$key', { enumerable: false, value: key}) :
          { $key: key, $value: value };
      });
```

In logs you can see answer to your question:

```
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 b b
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 a a
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 c Object {p: "c"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 b Object {p: "b"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 a Object {p: "a"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 c Object {p: "c", $key: "c"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 b Object {p: "b", $key: "b"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 a Object {p: "a", $key: "a"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 c c
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 b b
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 a a
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 c Object {p: "c", $$hashKey: "object:11", $key: "c"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 b Object {p: "b", $$hashKey: "object:10", $key: "b"}
VM596 angular-toArrayFilter.js:15 a Object {p: "a", $$hashKey: "object:9", $key: "a"}
```

In case objects, angular is using the same objects and does not create new ones. So that it can assume that array did not change and end digest cycle. In case of string values it creates new objects each time filter is run, so that it assumes that each time different array is created, so that it cannot end digest cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sielakos.
My plunker was failing in purpose, to highlight the failing behavior, I updated  it with the working case to make things clearer.

Comment: About your second point @sielakos, if the object properties being iterated over are not objects then the filter will replace the non-object with a new object of the form: { $key: key, $value: value }.

You states that it's a bad idea to use a filter in that case, but the Angular Doc explicitly suggest the toArrayFilter when we have the need to use orderBy when using ng-repeat and an object. What alternative do you suggest ?

Comment: Transform your data in controller/service this way you will not have to tranform them very time digest cycle runs, you will do that only once. Also you can avoid problems with infinite digest cycle.

Comment: It was failing for the wrong reasons, toArray filter was expecting objects.  There was no infinite digest cycle.

Comment: My mistake, my plunker used an old version of toArray. I updated it, now you can see the infinite digest loop exception if you open the console.

Comment: @Mic, I edited my answer to better explain why I think this is happening.